# Is it possible to wrap a container in SSIS with a transaction using 2 Execute SQL tasks?

Tags: t-sql, ssis, transactions

I want to wrap the sequence container in a transaction, so that the user can choose whether to insert their data. 
However, with

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION T1;
```

in "Begin Transaction" and

```
IF ? = 0
   COMMIT TRANSACTION T1
ELSE
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION T1;
```

in "Rollback or Commit Transaction", an error is thrown saying that the last task does not have a begin statement that it binds too.

[image: Control Flow of how I want the transaction to work]

Is there another way to achieve a transaction over a container, or do some package properties need to be changed for this to work?

P.S. The package will be ran by a C# form, so if there is a way to instead wrap the package in a transaction from C#, that option is also available

Thanks for any help or advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting all tasks to Supported on TransactionOption, and adding checks to see if there is a transaction active, like this

```
DECLARE @TranCount int;

SET @TranCount = (select COUNT(*) from sys.sysprocesses WHERE open_tran > 0);

IF @TranCount > 0
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

The whole container is wrapped in a transaction, and rolls back / commits without error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an option build into SSIS.  You select the Sequence and go to properties.  Under TransactionOption put the value to "required".
This requires MSDTC to be running, though.

Comment: MSDTC is running, and now that I have changed the TransactionOption to "Required" a new error is thrown. "Current Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) transaction must be committed by remote client."

Comment: Did you remove the Begin and Commit/rollback transaction tasks?

Comment: If I remove those tasks then how will I be able to choose whether to commit or rollback?

Comment: You can put a SQL task in the sequence to raise an error and only execute this based on your condition.

Comment: The condition chooses whether to rollback or commit, so if I remove the transaction tasks, how will putting a RAISERROR task allow me to rollback?

Comment: When there is an error in the sequence, SSIS will do the rollback for you.

Comment: Will it rollback any nested transactions in the DataFlow?

Comment: Yes the whole sequence container

Comment: I have tested this and it does not rollback the changes made in dataflow